# Call to undefined function session_is_registered()

Tags: php, session

I'm getting this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_is_registered() in /home/tunalima/domains/mywebsiteaddress.com.tr/public_html/_globals.php on line 11
Here is my code:

```
<? 
$s_uye_id = 0;
$s_uye_tipi = 0;
$s_uye_adi = "";
$s_uye_soyadi = "";
$s_mesaj = "";
$s_sayfa_url = "";
$s_ipimiz = "";


if (!session_is_registered("s_uye_id")) {
    session_register("s_uye_id");
    session_register("s_uye_tipi");
    session_register("s_uye_adi");
    session_register("s_uye_soyadi");
    session_register("s_mesaj");
    session_register("s_sayfa_url");
    session_register("s_ipimiz");
}



$turkce_aylar = array ( "Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık");

$turkce_harfler_buyuk = array ("", "A", "B", "C", "Ç", "D", "E", "F", "G", "Ğ", "H", "I", "İ", "J", "K", 
                         "L", "M", "N", "O", "Ö", "P", "R", "S", "Ş", "T", "U", "Ü", "V", "Y", "Z");
$turkce_harfler_kucuk = array ("", "a", "b", "c", "ç", "d", "e", "f", "g", "ğ", "h", "ı", "i", "j", "k", 
                         "l", "m", "n", "o", "ö", "p", "r", "s", "ş", "t", "u", "ü", "v", "y", "z");

$tum_harfler_buyuk = array ("", "A", "B", "C", "Ç", "D", "E", "F", "G", "Ğ", "H", "I", "İ", "J", "K", 
                         "L", "M", "N", "O", "Ö", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "Ş", "T", "U", "Ü", "V", "w", "X", "Y", "Z");

$firma_harfler_buyuk = array ("", "A", "B", "C", "Ç", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "İ", "J", "K", 
                         "L", "M", "N", "O", "Ö", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "Ş", "T", "U", "Ü", "V", "W", "Y", "Z");

$sadece_turkce_harfler_buyuk = array ("Ç", "Ğ", "İ", "Ö", "Ş", "Ü");
$sadece_turkce_harfler_kucuk = array ("ç", "ğ", "ı", "ö", "ş", "ü");
$isaretler = array (" ", ".", ",", "!", "'", "^", "+", "%", "&", "/", "(", ")", "=", "?", "]", "~", "`", "*", "#", "$", "|", "[", "-");
?>
```

Comment: **Warning

This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.** http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (!session_is_registered("s_uye_id")) {
```

type this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["s_uye_id"])) {
```

Head of script:

```
<?php
  session_start(); 
  $s_uye_id = 0;
  $s_uye_tipi = 0;
  $s_uye_adi = "";
  $s_uye_soyadi = "";
  $s_mesaj = "";
  $s_sayfa_url = "";
  $s_ipimiz = "";


  if (!isset($_SESSION["s_uye_id"])) {
      $_SESSION["s_uye_id"] = 
      $_SESSION["s_uye_tipi"] =
      $_SESSION["s_uye_adi" =
      $_SESSION[s_uye_soyadi"] = 
      $_SESSION[s_mesaj"] =
      $_SESSION[s_sayfa_url"] =
      $_SESSION[s_ipimiz"] = 0;
     }

  // continue ....
```

Answer (score 2):

nothing more to say then: function has been removed if your using php 5.4.0 or greater